# Extracting lambda expression from LINQ

Tags: c#, lambda, hyperlink, refactoring

I have next chunk of code

```
var query = wordCollection.Select((word) => { return word.ToUpper(); })
                          .Where((word) =>
                                  {
                                      return String.IsNullOrEmpty(word);
                                  })
                          .ToList();
```

Suppose I want to refactor this code and extract the lambda expression from Where clause. In Visual Studio I just select this lambda and do Refactor -> Extract Method. By doing so I have my LINQ modified to

```
 var query = wordCollection.Select((word) => { return word.ToUpper(); })
                          .Where(NewMethod1())
                          .ToList();
```

and a NewMethod1() is declared as

```
  private static Func<string, bool> NewMethod1()
  {
      return (word) =>
      {
          return String.IsNullOrEmpty(word);
      };
  }
```

The question is why this new method does NOT have any input parameters, as delegate Func states that NewMethod1() should have a string input parameter?

Comment: because it created a method that returns a delegate. Not a method that matches the delegate. What you expected was a method with a `string` parameter and a `bool` return type.

Comment: It does look wonky because as the person above said, yes it does look at face value that its a function that shouldnt compile - but its returning the delegate, not the result of the code, so, it is how it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the expected result, mark just this part `String.IsNullOrEmpty(word)` and Extract the method:

```
private bool NewMethod(string word)
{
    return String.IsNullOrEmpty(word);
}
```

What you originally got is because the extract created a method that returns a delegate. Not a method that matches the delegate. It is a method that returns another method. The latter accepts a string parameter `word` and returns a bool result.

Sure doing the above changes your code to:

```
.Where((word) => NewMethod(word))
```

But you can safely change that to:

```
.Where(NewMethod)
```

### Side Note:

No need to use the `return` keyword in your Linq Queries or any one-line lambda, you can refactor you query to be like this:

```
var query = wordCollection.Select(word => word.ToUpper())
                          .Where(word => string.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                          .ToList();
```

Comment: Using the same logic, couldn't you take it a step more to make `var query = wordCollection.Select(word => word.ToUpper()).Where(String.IsNullOrEmpty).ToList();`?

Comment: @SunnyPatel It can be written that way, but I preferred the posted one as it easier and clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the whole lambda, so it is trying to extract the whole lambda statement as a delegate that takes in a word and returns a boolean - Func < string, bool>.

When refactoring you should have only selected the "return String.IsNullOrEmpty(word);" part.

Additionally, you are using the lambas in an unnecessarily complex way.

You could refactor your LINQ statement to this:

```
var query = wordCollection.Select(word => word.ToUpper())
                  .Where(word => String.IsNullOrEmpty(word))
                  .ToList();
```

Or even to this:

```
var query = wordCollection.Select(word => word.ToUpper())
                  .Where(String.IsNullOrEmpty)
                  .ToList();
```